# Deploying Static React (Vite) App to DigitalOcean Droplet

Tags: shared-hosting, deployment, react-js

I have a static website created using the vite app. I know I can deploy my website on netlify, vercel or digitalocean app platform.

However, these platforms offer only 100GB bandwidth and for extra bandwidth, they charge so much. DigitalOcean droplet offers 1TB bandwidth for 6 dollars and I want to deploy my website there. But I really could not find a tutorial for how to deploy a static website to droplets.